# Is there a way to get smooth css keyframes animation?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make a loading icon, In which a line continuously move back and forth in z axis. The lines are moving but I am not getting smooth transitions.

```css
    .loading{
      width: 50%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 300px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .line{
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 20px;
      height: 140px;
      animation: round 2s infinite;
    }
    @keyframes round{
      25%{
        margin-right: -300px;
        height: 75px;
      }
      50%{
        height: 50px;
        width: 7px;
      }
      75%{
        margin-right: 300px;
        height: 75px;
      }
      100%{
        height: 140px;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="loading">
      <div class="line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> When line comes to main position it kind of stop and then start moving, how to get linear animation.

Comment: google for linear ease css. Add linear right after infinite

Answer (score 2):

For a `linear` easing animation do like

```
infinite linear;
```

For performace don't use margin or position properties. Use `transform: translate(x, y)` instead.

PS: Z axis is usually expressed for depth...

Comment: This cannot be emphasized enough. There are actually very few properties that take advantage of hardware acceleration to produce super smooth animations consistently. This article breaks it down very well and provides example that you can clearly see the jank, and how to fix it: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/12/gpu-animation-doing-it-right/